# How can I merge list items that are between spaces? - Python

Tags: python

How can I merge list items that are between spaces in a list. For examples:

```
lst = ['a a a',' ', ' ', ' ', 'b b b','c c c','d d d', ' ',' ', 'e e','f', ' ', 'g']
```

To this:

```
new_list = ['a a a', 'b b b c c c d d d', 'e e f', 'g']
```

I seem not to be able to work out the logic in my code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in a list comprehension and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['a',' ', ' ', ' ', 'b','c','d', ' ',' ', 'e','f',' ', 'g']

new_list = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x!=' ') if k]
```

output: `['a', 'bcd', 'ef', 'g']`